# How do i use the error level in this case?

Tags: batch-file

how do i use errorlevel to echo a number only if it works

```
:LOG
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > F:\Logs\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 1
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > F:\Logs-s\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 2
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > D:\Logs\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 3
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > D:\Logs-s\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 4
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > G:\Logs\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 5
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > G:\Logs-s\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 6
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > J:\Logs\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 7
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > J:\Logs-s\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 8
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > Q:\Logs\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 9
dir /s /b /ad c:\*.* > Q:\Logs-s\10%random%.txt
if errorlevel 0 echo 10
call :c 0F " C Drive Copyed
goto UNLOCK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use also

```
if NOT errorlevel 1 echo number
```

`NOT errorlevel 1` means lower than 1.

See the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/69576) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo 1` if what you have isn't working, but it should be.